# Issue with deep and wide model in keras

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to follow online tutorials and put together code for a wide and deep model in Keras. However, I'm having issues merging both models together

```
wide = Sequential()
wide.add(Dense(1, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], kernel_initializer ='uniform', activation='relu'))

deep = Sequential()
deep.add(Dense(1, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], kernel_initializer ='uniform', activation='relu'))
deep.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
deep.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
deep.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([wide, deep], mode='concat', concat_axis=1))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
```

The following warning occurs:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge([wide, deep], mode='concat', concat_axis=1))
__main__:2: UserWarning: The `Merge` layer is deprecated and will be removed after 08/2017. Use instead layers from `keras.layers.merge`, e.g. `add`, `concatenate`, etc
```

The warning message tells me what to do, but I've yet to figure out how to combine the two models.

I've tried different things like the following, but keep getting errors.

```
from keras.layers import add
model = Sequential()

model.add([wide, deep])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-428-3e81d6d35c6f>", line 1, in <module>
    model.add([wide, deep])

  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 430, in add
    'Found: ' + str(layer))

TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: [<keras.models.Sequential object at 0x1a32876cc0>, <keras.models.Sequential object at 0x1a328761d0>]
```

Can anyone tell me how to concat the wide and deep models with keras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are trying to merge models inside a Sequential model. In this case you will need to expand to the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) because you need calculate the the outputs of both models before you can merge them. Something along the lines of:

```
in = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1],)
wide_out = wide(in)
deep_out = deep(in)
wide_deep = concatenate([wide_out, deep_out]) # or any merge layer
out = Dense(1, activation='linear')(wide_deep)
model = Model(in, out) # Your final model
```

In a nutshell, in the functional API layers are like function that apply the set operations to the given layers creating the corresponding computation graph.

Comment: Final line results in TypeError: Output tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors. Found: <keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x1a21f292e8>

Comment: True, fixed, forgot to call the layer with the previous output.